# Using struct or class to store a object

Tags: .net, architecture

I have a problem about designing. I should use class or struct in this case. Example:

struct DataTicker
{
sring Symbol;
decimal Price;
decimal Volume;
}

class DataTicker
{
string Symbol;
decimal Price;
decimal Volume;
}

Assume that I have 3 projects: client, server & library. Library will define DataTicker object. Client & server will reference to this library to use this object. Client & server will send & transfer data, data can be a DataTicker object or a list of DataTicker object.

I should define DataTicker as a class or struct. And in future, If I add new fields in DataTicker and update library only at server (server will use a new DataTicker with more 3 fields), client still use old library (DataTicker with 3 fields) and can parse new DataTicker object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would definitely go with class because you have a reference type (string) as a datamember.

Comment: a blogged about it a while back : http://www.basarat.com/2011/04/reference-types-inside-value-type.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific reason for using a struct, you should probably just use a class.

As for the second part of your question, it depends, of course, on how you are doing your serialization and data transfer. If you are doing it with any of the standard ways built into .net, I suspect the answer is sadly **no**.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to define an interface and program against that; you can then implement structs / classes as required.